# How to exclude ELF 64-bit LSB shared object from uploading to git?

Tags: git, extension, github

I'm trying to include `ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked` files generated in gitignore by including `.elf` extension in .gitignore file but it's not working.

Please help!

Comment: Does the file have a `.elf` extension? `.gitignore` doesn't examine the contents of the file, only the name and path.

Comment: The file has no extension. When i enter `file file_name` i get `ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=cd62fa73c4967943119c4535db916c79db220f52, not stripped`

Answer (score 0):

Since generated binaries don't have a filename extension on Linux systems (unlike Windows `.exe`) files, there is no way to generically ignore all of them in `.gitignore`. You have to list each one separately.

Example: https://github.com/shundhammer/qdirstat/blob/master/src/.gitignore

```
...
qdirstat
...
```

Yes, that's annoying, and no, there is no better solution. But since you know what executables you create, and there is usually only one (or at most a very small number), it's not a big deal.

Comment: I added the file names directly in the `.gitignore` file but still, they're getting committed.

Comment: Are those files already in the git repo? In that case, `.gitignore` does not have any effect. Also make sure you either add it to the `.gitignore` in the same directory, or, if you use one some directory level(s) up, add the relative path.

Comment: As earlier they were already uploaded, first I deleted them from the repo and then made the changes in `.gitignore` and committed the changes but still those files got uploaded. The shared object files are not present in the same directory but inside a subdirectory whose relative path I added to the `.gitignore` file with the file name. The shared object files are formed after the compilation of D files, which creates an object file and the above-mentioned ELF shared object file.